# Wordpress check box unchecked on null value ternary operator [plugin development]

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to use wordpress plugin development, without a checked checkbox getting an error.

```
<?php global $options; ?>
<input name="settings[enable]" type="checkbox" id="" 
    value="1" <?php checked( $options['enable'], 1 ); ?> />
```

Comment: Does `print_r($options)` give you anything? Depending on the context this may or may not be the way you need to refer to the options. Also, your input name needs to be `settings['enable']` with quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`checked()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L4374) only checks if the passed first and second parameters match. It doesn't do any array key checking, so you need to do it yourself before using the function to avoid errors.

```
<?php 
  global $options;
  $enabled = ( isset( $options['enable'] ) ) ? $options['enable']: '';
?>
<input name="settings['enable']" type="checkbox" id="" value="1" <?php checked( $enabled, 1 ); ?>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is work for me . `<input name="settings[enable]" type="checkbox" id="" value="1" <?php if (isset($options['enable']) && (1 == $options['enable'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />`

Comment: Yes, checking if the key exists and if the value is the correct one yourself is a another way to do the same thing. `checked()` basically does the `(1 == $options['enable'])) echo 'checked="checked"'` part of your code.